# Variables within gtk_label_set_markup

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

As in title, is there a way to put variables into the string that is processed by `gtk_label_set_markup()` function?

More specifically, I call this function like this:    `gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(labelRed), "<span font=\"14\" color=\"red\"><b>\t\tRed: 999"</b></span>");`

But, instead of a static text that is '**999**', I want to put in this place an integer variable. Is it possible to do?

Greetings,
WisNia

Comment: You should provide examples of what you've already done, researched etc etc... Google is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`g_strdup_printf()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup-printf) to build a string and pass it to `gtk_label_set_markup()`:

```
char *str = g_strdup_printf ("<span font=\"14\" color=\"red\">"
                               "<b>\t\tRed: %d</b>"
                             "</span>",
                             value);

gtk_label_set_markup (GTK_LABEL (labelRed), str);

g_free (str); // remember to free the string allocated by g_strdup_printf()
```